# Javascript touchmove event on scroll element

Tags: javascript

so, I have a problem about getting element to moving on touchmove event.

this is my code :

```
<ul>
    <li>this is long Text</li>
    <li>this is long Text</li>
    <li>this is long Text</li>
    <li>this is long Text</li>
</ul>

ul {list-style:none; overflow-y:scroll; white-space:nowrap; }
ul li {display:inline-block; width:600px; margin-right:10px; }

document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0].addEventListener("touchmove", function(e) {
        var touch = e.touches[0] || e.changedTouches[0];
          var elm = this.offsetLeft;
          var x = touch.pageX - elm;

          this.scrollLeft = x;
              console.log(x);

});
```

[this is how it look](https://jsfiddle.net/kfwwdaqd/7/)

how to make this things move on touchmove event?

just like play.google.com mobile view do on their game product images?

i know it's moving if i click/touch on scrollbar, what i supposed to do here,

it's moving if i touch and move on UL element not the scrollbar.

thanks you..

Comment: It is moving on touchmove....

Comment: yeah it's moving on if u click/touch on scrollbar. but not on UL element.

Comment: `touchmove` event is for touch mobile devices. You can't "touch" in a scrollbar in mobile devices. Explain better what you need.

Comment: i'm using firefox touch view developer tools. i already check the console log. and it shows "trigger" but not moving the UL element to the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use the mousewheel js

```
$('ul').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
  this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 20);
  event.preventDefault();   
});
```

The "20" represents speed. preventDefault ensures the page won't scroll down.
Works on touch devices as well. Touch to scroll.

Here is an example: [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eJJZpW)

Comment: thanks joashp for answering my question. actually this is not what i suppost want to, would u like to take a look my fiddle? i just edited it.

Comment: @ChingChing its the same thing. Can you explain better what you are trying to achieve? Here is slider like play.google.com app screenshot view http://www.zackgrossbart.com/hackito/touchslider/

Comment: exactly joashp! that's what i want to build. i'm struggle on this code. basiclly it's already moving. but if i touch again it will back to at first point. why this is happening?